# What would be the best way to order a json object by an index found within each of it's properties?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects like so

```
obj = [
    {
      id: 3,
      data: foo
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      data: bar
    }
]
```

but I need to get it to

```
 obj = {
    3: {
        id: 3,
        data: foo
    },
    7: {
        data: bar
    }
 }
```

having the id in the sub object is not needed but might be handy. What would be the best way to achieve this? I am not sure if there is a simple way to extract a property as an index?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj2 = {};
obj.forEach(function(x){
    obj2[x.id] = x;
});
```

Comment: Sweet, I just came back to write something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you're working with object manipulation you should consider using the [Underscore JavaScript library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). It really makes working with them much easier and will deal with browser incompatibilities for you. Specifically here I would use the [`map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map) function:

```
var newObj = _.map(obj, function (subobj) {
  var tempObj = {};
  tempObj[subobj.id] = subobj;
  return tempObj;
});
```